# Limit with variable exponent

Tags: limits

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n),g(n) \in [0,1]$ , $q\in (0.5,1)$ and $f(n) \leq g(n)$. Also assume $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ converge to some real number in $[0,1]$. What is $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg(\Big({f(n) \over g(n)}\Big)^q \Big({1-f(n) \over 1-g(n)}\Big)^{(1-q)}\Bigg)^n$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $q$ doesn’t have to be a natural number, then why does $n$ have to be a natural number?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw it's related to Bernoulli, n is the number of trials.

Comment: oh ok.  Now I understand.

Comment: Presumably, $g(n)\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Try with $f(n)=g(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and then with $f(n)=\frac{\alpha}{n}$ and $g(n)=\frac{\beta}{n}$ where $0<\alpha<\beta<1$.